# How php parse the url parameter?

Tags: php, null, isset

I have a url

```
www.example.com?para1=&para2=2
```

I try to  judge the para1 and para2  ;

```
isset($_GET['para1'] )       // true
 isset($_GET['para2'])       //true;
 isset($_GET['para3'])       // false
```

I think that `isset($_GET['para1'] )` is false ,but it seems not .

## My problem :

why `isset($_GET['para1'] )` is true.How it parse the url  in php?

Comment: The parameter exists, even if it is empty. Test if it is empty after the isset test.

Comment: `para1` exists with an empty value. If you want to see if it exists and isn't empty, use: `empty($_GET['para1'])`. ``

Comment: how url  parse  in php?why  para1 is exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of people here are saying the value of a `$_GET['para1']` is `null` but that is not the case. There is [a comment on the php.net $_GET docs](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php#98419) that provides a useful script to test this.

Given the URL: `http://www.example.com?a`

You can use this script to test results:

```
<?php
print_r($_GET);
if($_GET["a"] === "") echo "a is an empty string\n";
if($_GET["a"] === false) echo "a is false\n";
if($_GET["a"] === null) echo "a is null\n";
if(isset($_GET["a"])) echo "a is set\n";
if(!empty($_GET["a"])) echo "a is not empty";
?>
</pre>
```

The output would be:

```
a is an empty string
a is set
```

This is the case because **a key without a value is actually an empty string** *not* `null`

So to directly answer your question:

Even though it does not appear `para1` has a value set, it actually does. The value is an empty string (`""`). Even though this value is falsy, it is still a value and as such, `isset()` returns true. You can use `!empty()` to return false on empty strings. See a comparison of `isset()` `empty()` and `is_null()` [here](https://www.virendrachandak.com/techtalk/php-isset-vs-empty-vs-is_null/).

Comment: Just run the script

Answer (score 1):

`isset($var)` will return `true` because the parametre exists in the url, if you check its value you gonna find an empty string `""`.

you can also use `empty($var)` function, to test for empty values, just pay attention that empty will return true for values like :

```
0, "", [], null, false ---> empty() return true
```

other wise it will return false

I usually get parametres and give them default value if they don't exist using a function like this one :

```
function get($item, $type = 'string', $default = null, $escape = true)
{
   if(!isset($_GET[$item])) {
     return $default;
   }

   $output = $_GET[$item];

   settype($output, $type);

   return $escape ? htmlspecialchars(trim($output)) : $output;
}

echo get('para1');
echo get('name', 'string', '');
echo get('admin', 'bool', false);
```

try the edit the function as you like, hope this help

Answer (score 1):

`isset($var)` returns `true` if the variable is defined, regardless of the value (except `null`). In your case, it is defined but contains an empty string.
You'd want to use `empty($var)` which does not throw an exception if the variable is not defined and tests for actual content.

[Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

> Determine whether a variable is considered to be empty. A variable is
>   considered empty if it does not exist or if its value equals FALSE.
>   empty() does not generate a warning if the variable does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

`isset()` returns true because it is set in your request but to an empty string.

You want to use `!empty()`.

In your request `www.example.com?para1=&para2=2`

`para1=null` and `para2=2`

So:

```
if (!empty($_GET['para1'])) {}
```

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Ahh yes thank you, I have updated the answer to use both.

Comment: I've already changed the answer to use `empty()` instead of `is_null()` :)

Comment: Then you can remove the `isset()` since `empty()` does the same as `isset()` _plus_ checks if the value is considered empty. :-)

Comment: Didn't know `empty()` did an `isset()` check. You learn something new everyday, thanks :) Updated answer

Comment: The value of a parameter with an unassigned value is not `null` it is an empty string. You can test this by running `if($_GET['para1'] === null){ echo "a is null\n";} else { echo "not null";}`

Answer (score 0):

Here are some few tips you that could help to achieve what you need:

- To check if var is set,

  ```
  isset($var)
  ```
- To check if var is set and not empty,

  ```
  !empty($var)
  ```
- To check if var is not empty and not white spaces,

  ```
  !empty($var) && !trim($var) == false
  ```

Answer (score -1):

The value exists in the `$_GET` array but his value is null,the function `isset` only evaluate if the value is initialized, not if the value is truthy.

If you want to know if the value is truthy, you can compare the array index with the `==` operator, like this `var_dump($_GET['para1'] == true)`

Comment: The value is not `null` it is an empty string, see my answer. You can test this by running `f($_GET['para1'] === null){ echo "param is null\n";} else { echo "not null";}`

Comment: You're right, I tried to say a falsy value, not `null`. Thanks.